# Проблема сборки проекта Qt по Android

Tags: android, qt, c++

Ведется разработка 2-х Qt проектов (Project_1 и Project_2).

Работа ведется на двух компьютерах (Comp_1 и Comp_2). При этом Project_1 находится под системой контроля версий Git, а Project_2 передается на другой компьютер в виде архива.

Проекты разрабатываются под Desktop и Android.

Кроме стандартной библиотеки Qt.5.4, в Project_1 также используются библиотеки: Papyros [qml-material](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material/tree/master) и [qml-extras](https://github.com/papyros/qml-extras).

Project_2 был создан на Comp_2. Собирается без проблем как под Desktop, так и под Android на обоих компьютерах. Также без проблем запускается и под Desktop, и под Android.

Project_1 был создан на Comp_1, на котором без проблем собирается и запускается как под Desktop, так и под Android.

Project_1 на Comp_2 был клонирован с помощью Git. Под Desktop проект собирается и запускается без проблем, а вот под Android собираться не хочет с такой, вот, ошибкой:

> Import found outside of import paths:
> /home/opt/Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml/Material/ListItems.
>
> 14:57:44: Процесс
> «/opt/Qt/5.4/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt» завершился с кодом 4. Ошибка при
> сборке/установке проекта Project_1
> (комплект: Android для armeabi-v7a
> (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.0) )
>
> Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка
> Android APK»

По указанному в сообщении сборщика пути:

> /home/opt/Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml/Material/ListItems.

Необходимые библиотеки на Comp_2 присутствуют. Права на папки и файлы - аналогичные другим папкам и файлам.

Настройки QtCreator и проектов одинаковые у обоих проектов на обоих компьютерах.

Требуется помощь, чтобы разобраться с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавив в pro-файл проекта Project_1 на Comp_2 строку:

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH = /home/opt/Qt/5.4/android_armv7/qml/Material/
```

После этого проект Project_1 стал собираться под Android на Comp_2.